# How to sort Date in java

Tags: java, sorting, datetime

I i have List AttendedExamName objects

```
public class AttendedExamName {
    private String name;
    private String dateTime;

  //getters    
  //settrs    
}
```

I try to sort based on dateTime property, when try to sort objects using below code

```
Collections.sort(examNames, (n1,n2)-> {
            try {
                Date date1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss").parse(n1.getDateTime());
                Date date2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss").parse(n2.getDateTime());
                return date1.compareTo(date2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }           
            });
```

I get this result:

```
[[name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-04.37.57],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-06.31.52], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-24-02.17.37], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-26-05.10.29],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-27-03.30.34],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-12.11.09],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-01.16.59],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-02.10.54],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.31.16],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.57.56]]
```

Expected:

```
[[name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-04.37.57],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-06.31.52], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-24-02.17.37], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-26-05.10.29],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-27-03.30.34],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.31.16],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.57.56],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-12.11.09],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-01.16.59],
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-02.10.54]]
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Why should `2017-04-28-01.16.59` be after `2017-04-28-12.11.09`? Note that your date format states `hh.mm.ss` which would indicate 12-hour formats but in that case the am/pm identifier is missing (which would be represented as `a` in the pattern). Thus the parser assumes both times to be am and hence 01:xx:xx is smaller than 12:xx:xx.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to store the dateTime as an actual `LocalDateTime` in your `AttendedExamName` class?

Comment: Hi, I havnt tested this, but you should just change `yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss`. This will convert it to 24hour format, and the sorting should be correct?

Comment: @kkflf You saw it too ;-) ... upvoting elsewhere thus...

Comment: And a nice question; for once containing all the relevant information.

Answer (score 6):

Nice one: the problem is here:

```
yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss
```

That expects hours to go up to 12. But you want 24 hour system, so your string format should be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss
```

Quoting the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> H Hour in day (0-23)
>
> h Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Beyond that: I would recommend to **not** write down that Comparator as lambda expression given to sort(). That thing is worth its own inner class; or alternatively: implement the `Comparable` interface on your class! And for the record: you also want to avoid that code duplication. Writing down the format string twice is already creating code duplication; thus giving potential for bugs.

And of course: why store strings in that class in the first place? You should do that transformation to real dates ONCE and store data objects, instead of doing it zillions of times during sorting!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a lambda, I am assuming you are using Java 8 (or later). In this case there is no reason why you would want the trouble with the oldfashioned `Date` class. `LocalDateTime` introduced in Java 8 is generally more programmer-friendly.

The best solution is if you can change the instance variable in your class to have type `LocalDateTime`:

```
private String name;
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

With your getter in place the way to sort by an attribute in Java 8 is:

```
    Collections.sort(examNames, Comparator.comparing(AttendedExamName::getDateTime));
```

Result:

```
[[name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15T04:37:57], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15T06:31:51], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-24T02:17:37], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-26T05:10:29], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-27T03:30:34], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28T11:31:16], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28T11:57:56], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28T12:11:09], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28T13:16:59], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28T14:10:54]]
```

I don’t know whehter I have guessed your intended times correctly, but you can fix that. Also `LocalDateTime` can of course be formatted with 12 hours and optional AM/PM marker if you require some of that.

What if you cannot change the type of the instance variable? I was first thinking that the exact same code would work. This is the case if it’s OK to sort the hours on the same date numerically from 01 to 12. Then you can just sort the `dateTime` strings as strings and get the correct chronological order. However, I am suspecting that you don’t want this order, though I have not fully understood the order you want.

One attempt would be:

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");
    Collections.sort(examNames, 
            Comparator.comparing(name -> LocalDateTime.parse(name.getDateTime(), format)));
```

Result:

```
[[name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-04.37.57], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-06.31.51], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-24-02.17.37], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-26-05.10.29], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-27-03.30.34], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-01.16.59], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-02.10.54], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.31.16], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.57.56], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-12.11.09]]
```

This is not quite the order you said you expected. Instead, let me assume that all your times are between 11 AM and 7 PM since this agrees with your expected order (11 and 12 come before 1 and 2, and 4 comes before 6). With `LocalDateTime` it’s not so bad:

```
    Collections.sort(examNames, Comparator.comparing(name -> {
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(name.getDateTime(), format);
        if (dt.getHour() < 9) {
            return dt.plusHours(12);
        } else {
            return dt;
        }
    }));
```

Now you get the expected order:

```
[[name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-04.37.57], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-15-06.31.51], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-24-02.17.37], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-26-05.10.29], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-27-03.30.34], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.31.16], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-11.57.56], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-12.11.09], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-01.16.59], 
 [name=SCJP, dateTime=2017-04-28-02.10.54]]
```

You may extend the code to check if the hour is within whatever your expected interval is and for example throw an exception if not.